# Handling function param that can str or list in Python

Tags: python, hug

I'm not an experienced Python programmer but I feel my solution to this problem isn't right, I think there is a better way to deal with this problem in Python.

In this case, this is using [Hug API](https://hugapi.github.io/hug/) but that's probably mostly irrelevant.

Let's say the code is like this:

```
@hug.get_post('/hello')
def hello (name)
   print(type(name))
   return name
```

When a request is sent with one instance of the `name` parameter, the `hello` function gets a `str` - as in:

```
POST /hello?name=Bob
```

But if the request is sent multiple `name` parameters, the method receives a `list` of strings, as in

```
POST /hello?name=Bob&name=Sally
```

If I write the method like the following:

```
@hug.get_post('/hello')
def hello (name: list)
   print(type(name))
   return name
```

Then the single parameter becomes a list of characters. I.e. `['B', 'o', 'b']`. But this works fine if there is multiple instances of the `name` parameter (e.g. `['Bob', 'Sally']` )

So the way I solved it right now is by adding this code:

```
@hug.get_post('/hello')
def hello (name)
   names=list()
   if type(name) != 'list'
      names.append(name)
   else:
      names=name
   return names
```

This works, but feels wrong. I think there is a better way to do this but I can't figure it out at the moment.

Comment: This is definitely incorrect: `if type(name) != 'list'` the result of `type` will never equal a string. `type` returns a class object, so here you would use `if type(name) is not list` but you should use `isinstance` for something more idiomatic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hug provides a type for that: `hug.types.multiple`

```
import hug
from hug.types import multiple

@hug.get()
def hello(name: multiple):
    print(type(name))

    return name
```

Now `/hello?name=Bob` returns `['Bob']` and `/hello?name=Bob&name=Sally` returns `['Bob', 'Sally']`.

If you want to validate the inner elements, you can create a customized type like this:

```
import hug
from hug.types import Multiple, number

numbers = Multiple[number]()

@hug.get()
def hello(n: numbers):
    print(type(n))

    return n
```

In this case `/hello?n=1&n=2` returns `[1, 2]` and `/hello?n=1&n=a` results in an error:

> {"errors": {"n": "Invalid whole number provided"}}

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be more concise you could use the ternary operator like so:

```
@hug.get_post('/hello')
def hello (name)
   return name if isinstance(name, list) else [name]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do it in a much more elegant matter.

`isinstance()` is a very common way of checking types.
Below code can handle tuples, lists or strings

```
@hug.get_post('/hello')
def hello (name):
   if isinstance(name, (list, tuple)):
      names = name
   else:
      names = [name]      
   return names
```